# Resizing struct / char array (to reduce memory usage)

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32

This is my first project on Arduino/C++/ESP32. I wrote a fairly big program and got almost everything working - except that in the end I realized that the device would run out of breath (memory) periodically and go for a reboot. The reboot is because I configured a watchdog to do so.

There is one area where I think there's a chance to reduce the memory usage but my experience on c++ is "not there yet" for me to be able to write this by myself. Any pointers (no pun intended) please? I have been on this since yesterday and getting rid of one error only results in another new error popping up. Moreover I don't want to come up with something that is hacky or might break later. It should be a quick answer for the experienced people here.

**Let me explain the code that I prefer to refactor/optimize.**

I need to store a bunch of records that I would need to read/manipulate later. I declared a struct (*because they are related fields*) globally. Now the issue is that I may need to store 1 record, 2 records or 5 records which I would only know later once I read the data from the EEPROM. And this has to be accessible to all the functions so it has to be a global declaration.

**To summarize**

**Question 1** - how to set "`NumOfrecs`" later in the program once the data is read from the eeprom.

**Question 2** - The size(`sizeOfUsername`) of the char array username can also change depending upon the length of the username read from the eeprom. At times it might be 5 characters long, at times it could be 25. I can set it to a max 25 and solve this problem but then wouldn't I be wasting memory if many usernames were just 4-5 characters long? So in short - just before copying over the data in eeprom into the "username" char array, is it possible to set it's size to the optimal size required for holding that data ( which is the data size + 1 byte for null termination ).

```
struct stUSRREC {
  char username[sizeOfUsername];
  bool online;
}; 

stUSRREC userRecords[NumOfrecs];
```

I familiarized myself with a whole bunch of functions like strcpy, memset, malloc etc but now I have run out of time and need to keep the learning part for another day.

I can try to do this in a slightly different manner where I don't use the struct and instead use individual char arrays ( for each field like username ). But then again I'll have to resize the arrays as I read the data from the eeprom.

I can explain all the things I have tried but that will make this question unnecessarily long and perhaps result in losing some clarity. Greatly appreciate any help.

While responding to Q&A on SO I was trying some random stuff and at least this little piece of code below seems to work ( in terms of storing smaller/bigger values )

```
struct stUSRREC {
  char username[];        
  bool online;                   
}; 

stUSRREC userRecords[5];
```

Then manipulate it this way

```
strcpy(userRecords[0].username, "MYUSERNAME");
strcpy(userRecords[0].username, "test");
strcpy(userRecords[0].username, "MYVERYBIGUSERNAME");
```

I have been able to write/rewrite different lengths (above) and can read all of them back correctly. Resizing "userRecords" might be a different game but that can wait a little

One thing I forgot to mention was that I will need to size/resize the array ( holding username ) ONLY ONCE. In the `setup()` itself I can read/load the required data into those arrays. I am not sure if that opens up any other possibility. The rest of the struct/array I need to manipulate during the running are only boolean and int values. This is not an issue at all because there is no resizing required to do so.

On a side note I am pretty sure I am not the only one who faced this situation. Any tips/clues/pointers could be of help to many others. The constraints on little devices like ESP32 become more visible when you really start loading them with a bunch of things. I had it all working with "Strings" (the capital S) but the periodic reboot (cpu starvation?) required me to get rid of the Strings. Even otherwise I hear that using Strings (on ESP, Arduino and gang) is a bad idea.

Comment: The size of a struct in C++ must be known at compile time, and cannot be changed.

Comment: Thanks. When you say size of the struct it would mean the size of members as well? Or can that be manipulated later? I am testing this out as I type. I knew there are many who had a bad day and taking it out by downvoting left right and center. I generally keep away from SO for this reason.

Comment: "When you say size of the struct it would mean the size of members as well?" Yes - those are what gives a struct its size.

Comment: Ok then I guess I am better off by using individual variables and then figure out how to size/resize them correctly. I guess I am going to have to experiment with malloc realloc calloc etc. My first try with malloc didn't go well so I left it at that to try other stuff.

Comment: You can't resize variables.

Comment: Perhaps I am not getting the meaning of "resize" correctly. I do see some similarity when I see code such as this Temp = realloc( Temp, sizeof(char *) * 3); This may not be the one that is a perfect fit to my problem but boy it does resize something :)

Comment: `char username[sizeOfUsername];` looks like you want `std::string username;` and `stUSRREC userRecords[NumOfrecs];` should probably be `std::vector<stUSRREC > userRecords;`

Comment: If you have to write back to the EEPROM later, remember to [serialize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) the `string` and the `vector`.

Comment: @user4581301 thanks that does ring a bell because I remember having read something similar. Btw my main intention in doing this is to get rid of the strings. I hear those Strings are a hog on the resources. That's why I replaced most of the Strings with char arrays.

Comment: @user4581301 luckily I don't have to write much back to the eeprom. It's probably just a boolean or an int which is easier, unlike the variable length strings.

Comment: They can be, but `std::string` makes the job so much easier that you should put up with them until you know for sure that they are a problem and that you need an alternate solution. In other words, start simple, test, and put up with the extra suffering only if you need to.

Comment: I have removed every single line of dead code, variables etc and now the only thing I am left with is to replace the strings with char arrays. .... Anything that can be changed to constant I changed it to constant. Then used PROGMEM etc to further cut down. Even found some stripped down versions of libraries to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You tagged this question as C++, so I'll ask:

Can you use `vector` and `string` in your embedded code?

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct stUSRREC {
  std::string username;
  bool online;
  stUSRREC(const char* name, bool isOnline) :
       username(name), 
       online(isOnline)
  {
  }
};

std::vector<stUSRREC> userRecords;
```

The use of `string` as the username type means you only allocate as many characters needed to hold the name instead of allocated an assumed max size of `sizeOfUsername`.  The use of `vector` allows you to dynamically grow your record set.

Then to add a new record:

```
stUSRREC record("bob", true);
userRecords.push_back(record);
```

And you may not need `NumOfrecs` anymore.  That's covered by `userRecrods.size()`

Comment: Thanks selbie. I just tried to compile and I got an error 'string' in namespace 'std' does not name a type. So I guess I cannot.

Comment: @R.W Arduino does not include the C++ standard library.  Instead you have the [`String`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/) class.  I don't believe Arduino provides a `vector`-like class.  You would have to implement that functionality yourself.

Comment: Yes Miles Budnek. I have been able to use the string class but not the vector. I was trying out messing with the struct as we speak I am adding something that seems to work (in terms of later resizing). Too early to say anything but I'll add the code to my question

Comment: It should be an academic exercise to add a minimal and viable string and vector class.

Comment: Thanks @selbie. I seem to be able to use "vector"! I am not sure if that is because of some libraries that I installed later. I was messing around with some STL libraries for ESP32 and Arduino. I will confirm this later. I tested a simple piece of code with vector (just std::vector<int> for now) and it compiled and executed just nice. So I guess using "vector" solves this problem. I am gona rewrite the stuff to use vector and see how it goes. I am marking your answer. Thanks a zillion. And also a great many thanks to others for the tips and pointers.

Comment: selbie, a quick question if I may - when reading that record back (in your example), I can read "online" without any problem but I can't read the username - that throws an error. Would be able to add a small example on reading the 2 values (username, online)? I tried converting/casting to string etc.Thanks.

Comment: I suspect your bug is something about the way you are trying to deference items in your vector.  Probably best to start a new question with an updated source code example.  You can link to the new question in the subsequent comment and I'll take a look (as will others).

Comment: Thanks, will do so. Btw I tried to access it like a C-style string using c_str(). I am not sure if it's the perfect way but this works - userRecords[0].username.c_str();

Comment: I posted my quick question as a new question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/55740114/3524579. Thanks selbie, the solution seems nearer.